# Number of items fetched per page gets reduced after some number of pages while fetching data from Azure cosmosDB using Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos container containing about 24K documents. I am fetching these in pages of size 200 using spring boot. Here's the snippet for the same:

```
public void ingest() {
    var page = itemProjectionHeimdallRepository.findAll(PageRequest.ofSize(200));
    totalItems = (int) page.getTotalElements();
    int pageCount = 0;
    while (pageCount < totalPageCount) {
      process(page);
      pageCount++;
      if (pageCount < totalPageCount) {
        page = itemProjectionHeimdallRepository.findAll(page.nextPageable());
      }
    }
  }
```

With this, I get proper number of records(200) per page upto 59 pages, but thereafter I keep getting only 25 records per page and the remaining records are lost. Which means after processing all the pages I don't have all the 24K records with me.

The source Cosmos container from where I am reading is provisioned with 3000 RU/s. Not sure what's going wrong.

Here's the dependency I am using in my POM for Spring data cosmos:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-cosmosdb</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using? For one you appear to be sharing data (`totalItems`). If this isn't the code, please provide the actual code (like if you have some dedicated `find*` method you are basically changing the underlying dataset impacting the query results.

Comment: no, this is the actual code. the `totalItems` in the project is used to simply log the total items in the container. The `findAll` is the one given by SpringData to fetch all the items from the container. Also, I can assure you the `process` method doesn't mutate anything in the `page`.

Comment: It does as it processes the content, but if this is the regular `findAll` I'm not sure why it doesn't return, could be an ordering issue (as you are querying without an order and it isn't garantueed). Check the queries that get generated, there is also a newer version, 2.3.1, of CosmoDB which you might try?